# How does Bane of the Trapped stack with Time Warp?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

The [Bane of the Trapped](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/bane-of-the-trapped) legendary gem has the effect:

> Increase damage against enemies under the effects of control-impairing effects by 15.00%.

Per numerous other sources, Slow Time counts as a "control-impairing effect."

The [Slow Time: Time Warp](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/slow-time) rune states the following:

> Enemies caught in the bubble of warped time take 15% more damage.

How does this damage bonus combine?  Is it additive or multiplicative?

Comment: Bane of the Trapped is multiplicative, don't know about bubble, but it should also be multiplicative. Don't have sources to cite, so leaving this as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I have seen a [thread on Battle.net](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/14058607023), attributing the information to some other site. The information can be obsolete, as it seems to date back to 2.0.6.*

All buffs are separated into several classes. Buffs in the same class are additive, classes are multiplicative.

**Class A** : regular buffs/debuffs/skills

- A1 : Self buffs towards sheet dps - Glass Cannon, Hexing pants, MW, Familiar, BH-SS etc.
- A2 : Most classical debuffs towards mobs - Strongarms, EE, Cold Blooded etc.
- A3 : Every skill damage *except Hydra* - MM%, BH% etc.

**Class B** : elemental & pets

- B1 : Elemental damage %
- B2 : Pet % (MoJ and Enforcer)

**Class C** : elitist affixes

- Damage dealt to elites / beasts / demons / humans is increased by %

**Class D** : Bane of the Trapped

**Class E** : Zei's Stone of Vengeance

**Class F** : Audacity

**Class G** : Hydra damage %

- Hydra damage - unlike all other skill%, Hydra is not in the buff/debuff class A.

So, your final damage bonus would be

```
A*B*C*D*E*F*G, A = A1+A2+A3, B = B1+B2
```

So, in your question BoT is definitely multiplicative with Time Warp (it is with everything), the question is - which other buffs you already have in class A, that would decrease Time Warp's effectiveness. I am playing a Del'Rasha Wizard, so I always have +100% Meteor damage on Nilfur's Boots. Thus, Time Warp adds at most 7.5% to my damage.

Comment: I was with you until the last paragraph.  I play a [Delsere/Vyr's hybrid](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/profile/Troyen-1170/hero/65579262) so I didn't get why something would reduce Time Warp's effectiveness?

Comment: @Troyen Something would reduce Time Warp's effectiveness by adding more buffs to class A (as I assume Time Warp falls into A2). In my example, if I always have +100% damage in A3, adding Time Warp makes class A +115%, which is only 7,5% better. In your case I do now know how Archon buffs work. If they are class A, you are in the same boat as me (or worse, if you easily pass +100% mark). That said, do you see Archon bonus anywhere in the character sheet? (I didn't play Archon in, like, forever)

Comment: Archon stacks do modify my character sheet damage number.

Comment: @Troyen Then, unfortunately, they fall into A1, progressively making Time Warp less and less significant :-( At least under model described, we can always hope it's wrong :-)