# How does Blur stack with resistances?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

The [Blur passive skill](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/passive/blur) states that it reduces damage taken by 17%.

Another answer stated that [different classes of damage buffs stack multiplicatively](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/244808/16953), so I would suspect that also applies to damage reduction buffs.  However, my character sheet shows this:

[image: Poison damage from level 70 enemies reduced by 85.38% + 16.99%]

I do not, in fact, have complete immunity to poison damage like those numbers would imply.

How much damage reduction do I really have with Blur?  And does the difficulty level negatively affect my resistances or just the amount of damage monsters do?

(If it's relevant, this screenshot was taken on Torment VI.)

Comment: If I recall correctly, Blur is multiplicative. I was under the impression that it is reflected in sheet Toughness and is plain times 1.17, but I don't have D3 at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start, Blur is Multiplicative, so your suspicion and Orc's comment was correct (old thread [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12673559083), but the actual damage formulas haven't changed). The tooltip for the poison resistance is in a way right, but it is not very clear. Your poison damage is reduced by 85.38% and another time reduced (the +) by 16.99%.

> How much damage reduction do I really have with Blur?

This means you won't get full immunity, because you actually get (1-85.38) * (1-16.99) = 12,14% of the initial damage.

> And does the difficulty level negatively affect my resistances or just the amount of damage monsters do?

Just the amount of damage monsters do (and the increased health of the monsters)